# Npm script can't run with terminal commands

Tags: javascript, npm-scripts

> -client@0.0.0 move-public
> mv ./dist/* ../server/public

'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I tried this  "move-public": "move .\dist\* ..\server\public", but did not move the directories.

Comment: If you're looking for a cross-platform way to move files in npm scripts, consider using shx.  https://github.com/shelljs/shx

Comment: You're trying to use the Unix `mv` command on Windows.